# Visual Studio custom project template with IWizard

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I would like to create a custom project template with wizard. 
As idea I took a MVC template in VS. First a created an multi project template and packed all in a zip file with My.vstemplate file

```
...
<TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.DataAccess">
            DataAccess\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Logic">
            Logic\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Types">
            Types\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
    </ProjectCollection>
</TemplateContent>
<WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>MyProjectWizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>MyProjectWizard.WizardImplementation</FullClassName>
</WizardExtension>
```

In wizard I would like to chose a same type for my project configuration like "empty" or "full" etc.

I don't know what should I do to "remove" not needed project from created solution or how can I replace configuration for template in RunStarted method.

```
public bool ShouldAddProjectItem(string filePath){...}
```

work only for item template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. If you need something like Xamarin or ASP project template, where user can chose a project type and configuration, you need to create more implementation for the [IWizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.templatewizard.iwizard?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2017) interface.

1. First for project (root wizard). It will be as  in .vstemplate file. Here you write logic for cancel, back button or for project names.
2. Second's wizard for the sub projects(subProject.vstemplate). Here you can declare new variables like NuGet version from some storage (db, file..) and checks, should you create this project for this config or throw cancel exception.